# What company makes video tripods with an oval logo containing a (not exactly Nike-like) "swoosh" curve?

Tags: tripod, video

I am hoping somebody can help me out with this tripod, I know its a video tripod but I don't know any of the specs or maker.  I would love to know what kind it is.  When the tripod is collapsed it measures 34". Has a very very large head. Hope to hear back from someone, Thanks

[image: this is the logo of the head]

Comment: Better to ask it in http://video.stackexchange.com/ for they know more about video equipment.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a Vanguard, and I'm putting +1 on the question to cancel out the negative...most tripod manufacturers don't restrict themselves to photo or video.

Take a look at http://www.vanguardworld.com/ and see if you can see any resemblance, or try google image search for 'vanguard logo'. It's the closest I can identify